# htaccess not working in ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello a couple months ago I started a website project, after weeks last night I continued developing it on my windows pc were everything worked fine.
Today I ported it to ubuntu 12.04 lts and after starting up my apache / mysql tried to hit some website urls.(set up with vhost like so: tms.localhost/path...)

The Issue I'm facing and I have no idea why is that the clean urls and the mod_rewrite doesn't seem to work. My custom php redirection - page loading script isn't being called anymore(index.php).

Here is the htaccess that is unchanged since day 1. Need to mention that works only if I just enter the vhost url like so `http://tms.localhost/` if i add anything after that I get the default apache 404 page.

```
#Debugging - Error reporting
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on

#Commpression
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c="">
    <filesmatch ".(js|css|html|png|jpg|jpeg|swf|bmp|gif|tiff|ico|eot|svg|ttf|woff|pdf)$"="">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

Options All -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # remove spaces from start or after /
    #RewriteRule ^(.*/|)[\s%20]+(.+)$ $1$2 [L,R=301,NE]
    # remove spaces from end or before /
    #RewriteRule ^(.+?)[\s%20]+(/.*|)$ $1$2 [L,R=301,NE]


    # replace spaces by - in between
    #RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1+$2 [L,R=301,NE]


    # Remove trailing slash
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Add trailing slash
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
    #RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301] 

    # Remove multiple slashes
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]

    # Clean url rewrite
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif|css|js|json)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^([^/]+/?.+)$ /index.php?req=$1 [L,QSA]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?req=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# Big thnx to anubhava for his regex help - linkedin.com/in/anubhava
```

**UPDATE**

The index.php works as a page file loader it doesn't contain any html.
Only the root url works and loads the corresponding php file, hence mod_rewrite is enabled.
htaccess fails to translate the rest of the requests I suppose ?

vhostfile tms.localhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@tms.localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/tms
    ServerName tms.localhost
    #ServerAlias www.example.com

</VirtualHost>
```

modules phpinfo() :

```
core mod_log_config mod_logio prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_status
```

Comment: Have you made sure that mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess file?

Comment: htaccess is at the root directory as index.php is. mod_rewrite is enabled.please check post update thnx :)

Comment: So both .htaccess and index.php are placed in `/var/www/tms` path?

Comment: And what is example of full URL that isn't working for you?

Comment: yes @anubhava. Also I'm not 100% sure but this might be because of this: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53929
The thing is that I haven't changed anything. Could it be because of an ubuntu update ?

Comment: http://tms.localhost/login, http://tms.localhost/signout, http://tms.localhost/signin, http://tms.localhost/users, Nothing works except http://tms.localhost/

Comment: Ok Is there `login.php` file there also?

Comment: All requests are redirected to index.php and based on the request (url path) the corresponding php file is being included. All files are present and have 777 permissions for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Well there was nothing wrong with it. 
Apparently either the compression program or google drive (where I kept the project renamed `.htaccess` to `htaccess`...